# PHP Connection to MongoDB with SSL

Tags: php, mongodb, ssl

I'm setting up a development environment with PHP creating a connection to MongoDB over SSL. The server is using a self-signed cert and I'm using the MongoDB PHP extension (Not the older Mongo extension). Server is CentOS 7, mongod is 3.2.6. Client is OS X with PHP 5.6.10 (MAMP). My mongod.conf has the following:

```
net:
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /data/ssl/mongodb.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

I verified my connection was working without SSL and verified I can connect from the console on the server. My PHP connection looks like this:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://" . $mongo_user . ":" . $mongo_pass . "@" . $mongoHost . "/" . $mongo_db, array(
        'ssl' => true,
        'sslAllowInvalidCertificates' => true,
        'host' => $mongoHost
    )
);
```

When trying to connect, I get the following:

```
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Anyone have any experience with this? I was under the impression that sslAllowInvalidCertificates would allow the connection even though the certificate is self-signed (assuming the self-signed cert is what is failing verification).

Thanks!

Comment: Please see related post [Google Groups mongodb-user: PHP Connection over SSL](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/zmirzLQWmL0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Google Group mentioned by Wan Bachtiar, my issue was that the MongoDB PECL extension had been built against a version of PHP that did not have OpenSSL included. I modified the environment to include OpenSSL, rebuilt the PECL MongoDB extension and that resolved the issue.